# How to load GeoJSON data in OpenLayers?

Tags: openlayers, geojson

I'm using GeoServer for serving map in the GeoJSON format. I din't find any working example.  Here is my code snippet.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/openlayers/openlayers.github.io@master/en/v6.0.1/css/ol.css"
    type="text/css">
  <style>
    .map {
      height: 85vh;
      width: 100%;
    }
  </style>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/openlayers/openlayers.github.io@master/en/v6.0.1/build/ol.js"></script>
  <title>OpenLayers example</title>
</head>

<body>
  <!-- <h2>My Map</h2> -->
  <div id="map" class="map"></div>
  <script type="text/javascript">

    var views = new ol.View({
      center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([84.1240, 28.3949]),
      // projection: 'EPSG:4326',
      zoom: 7,
      // rotation: -Math.PI / 8,
    })

    var base_layer = new ol.layer.Tile({
      source: new ol.source.OSM()

    })

    var vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector({
      format: new ol.format.GeoJSON(),
      url: function (extent) {
        return 'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/misproject/ows?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=misproject%3Aprovince_boundary&maxFeatures=50&outputFormat=application%2Fjson&srsname=EPSG:4326&' +
          'bbox=' + extent.join(',') + ',EPSG:4326';
      },
      strategy: new ol.loadingstrategy.bbox()
    });
    var province_boundary = new ol.layer.Vector({
      source: vectorSource,
      style: new ol.style.Style({
        stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
          color: 'rgba(0, 0, 255, 1.0)',
          width: 3
        })
      })
    })

    var map = new ol.Map({
      layers: [base_layer, province_boundary],
      target: 'map',
      view: views
    })
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

URL is working perfectly in the postman but not in the OpenLayers. Did I miss anything?

Answer (score 4):

OpenLayers passes the extent in view projection units so you should use that if your server supports it (otherwise you would need to transform the extent to EPSG:4326)

```
  url: function (extent, resolution, projection) {
    return 'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/misproject/ows?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=misproject%3Aprovince_boundary&maxFeatures=50&outputFormat=application%2Fjson&srsname=EPSG:4326&' +
      'bbox=' + extent.join(',') + ',' + projection.getCode();
```